# overflow:auto not working in FireFox 16

Tags: html, firefox

I know there are a lot of post about overflow problem in FF (most for old version) or elsewhere but I can't find something related to my example.

I tried this little piece of code which should produce a scrollbar : it works as expected in Chrome and IE but not in FireFox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><body>
 <div style="height: 25px; overflow: auto;">
   <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
 </div>
</body></html>
```

Here is an online example : http://jsfiddle.net/v7kqP/5/

​
I am using **FireFox 16.0.2**. Am I doing something wrong or is it a FF bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox won't show the vertical scrollbar if it thinks there's not enough space to show the whole thing.  Clearly it thinks 25 pixels is not enough space to show a vertical scrollbar, in your case...

Comment: True. Since v16 it seems FF needs 34px minimum to display a scrollbar ... whereas other browser don't !

Comment: Hmm.  That's a bit odd.  I'll look into what changed from 15 to 16 here.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm seeing the same minimum height for a scrollbar (about 60px) in both Firefox 15 and Firefox 16.  But that's on Mac.  I assume you're on Windows, right?

Answer (score 1):

It's scrollable. Try putting some content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><body>
<div style="height: 25px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid blue;"><div style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">Here goes the content......................................</div></div>
</body></html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v7kqP/9/)

Comment: This does not work for me ... But still, I expect it to have scrollbars with or without content !

Comment: I'm using Firefox 15. By the way I saw some major changes in v16. Some of my app are causing problems in v16.